# Mediawiki + Sub-domain + SSL returns 404 error when accessing secure site

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki

Using CPanel/Softaculous to install Mediawiki on my hosted website appears to install fine. Though not sure how much the installer checks.

I then setup a sub-domain such as wiki.mydomain.com to accept requests there.

After that, I also setup SSL cert in Cpanel. The cert is self-signed because at the moment I am just testing out the wiki and everything before I decided if I will purchase a cert.

Then, if I attempt to go to http://wiki.mydomain.com. I get the landing page of MediaWiki but if I attempt to go to https://wiki.mydomain.com I get nothing but a blank browser window.

Now, if i go to https://wiki.mydomain.com/index.php, I get a 404 error (I created a simple html page with a 404 error message then modified my .htaccess to show it on the 404).

When looking at the logs, it appears to be trying to find the index.php file under /home/mydomain/public_html/index.php instead of /home/mydomain/wiki/index.php.

Very confused on why this isn't working at all. I can post some configs and things as well but this account is a newly created CPanel account so not much as been done on it other then installing the wiki software.

<del>(Edit) This is using SharedSSL. I couldn't get it to work without it. Some reason even after I made sure the site was the only one on the IP Address using WHM it was still showing it as a shared IP. :P</del>

Fixed the SharedSSL by using this information: [Cpanel Forums](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/ssl-cert-500-internal-server-error-162653.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for this issue is due to how cPanel works with sub-domains and SSL. From what I gather, this appears to be a SSL cert issue since when CPanel rebuilds the httpd.conf using /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf command, it does not create a SSL virtual host for the sub-domain. Also, the parent domain works fine.

I ended up putting the wiki in /home/mydomain/public_html/wiki then setting up redirects for http://mydomain.com and https://domain.com to point to https://mydomain.com/wiki.

For now, that's all I could figure out to fix the issue was to drop the sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a new install of MediaWiki via Softaculous. Go on the install form you will get an option to "Choose Protocol" choose https:// there and in the "Choose Domain" dropdown choose your subdomain https://wiki.mydomain.com leave the "In Directory" field blank and then click on Install button.
Then you should be able to access the MediaWiki install at https://wiki.mydomain.com

Comment: I've done this but this only forces https for the site (especially forcing all links to be https that are to the site itself). Here's the info for it [Manual:$wgServer](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer)